# nodejs: UNMET DEPENDENCY type@module / How can I get `npm list` stop returning this error?

Tags: node.js, npm

```
D:\TEMP\nodejs\count>npm list
TEMP@ D:\TEMP
+-- file-type@17.1.1
+-- html2pdf.js@0.10.1
+-- html2pdf@0.0.11
+-- mysql@2.18.1
+-- sqlite3@5.0.3
`-- UNMET DEPENDENCY type@module

npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! missing: type@module, required by TEMP@

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Luuk\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-07T17_11_04_588Z-debug-0.log
```

- The logfile is of no help (to me)
- I did search using Google, but that was not leading to a solution.

I removed `nodejs` from my computer, then re-installed it This is giving the exact same error.

For re-installing I used [node-v18.12.1-x64.msi](https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.12.1/node-v18.12.1-x64.msi)

**EDIT: Installing using `node-v18.13.0-x64.msi` gives same problems.**

How can I get `npm list` stop returning this error?

BTW: The directory `D:\TEMP\nodejs\count` is an empty directory on My Windows 11 system.

BTW: The word `error` is mentioned here in that log file:

```
D:\TEMP\nodejs\count>findstr /i error "C:\Users\Luuk\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-07T17_11_04_588Z-debug-0.log"

38 verbose stack Error: missing: type@module, required by TEMP@
43 error code ELSPROBLEMS
44 error missing: type@module, required by TEMP@
48 error A complete log of this run can be found in:
48 error     C:\Users\Luuk\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-07T17_11_04_588Z-debug-0.log
```

EDIT:

- After removing the `node_modules` directory (`move node_modules node_modules.1`, in the directory `C:\Program Files\nodejs` )
- I did `npm cache clean` which produced:

```
D:\TEMP\nodejs\count>npm cache clean
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.13.0
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1039:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:885:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.13.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that i need to create a (emtpy) application using `npm init`, which will create a file name "package.json", which has the following contents (I entered "test", whan a name was asked, and just hit the enter button on the rest of the questions):

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

After this:

```
D:\TEMP\npm>npm list
test@1.0.0 D:\TEMP\npm
`-- (empty)
D:\TEMP\npm>npm update

up to date, audited 1 package in 72ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Answer (score 0):

NPM's dependency resolver seems to be broken a bit due to which NPM's security suggestions and tools such as NPM audit, NPM list cannot be trusted fully. Read this - https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1341#issuecomment-20634338

Here a quick fix for the issue that may help -

Step 1 - Remove **node_modules** directory

Step 2 - Run `npm cache clean`

Step 3 - Run `npm install`

Comment: See the `edit` for more info, on why this fails.

Comment: You're typing the wrong command. There's a typo mistake.

Comment: I corrected the output, I was indeed making a lot of typos yesterday....